# Use ChaiHttp with beforeEach or before method

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai

I have an NodeJS Express application which I want to unit test which uses cookies. So I want to use a beforeEach or before to create the Cookie.

Code which works without any problem (but without the before method):

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import { expect } from 'chai'
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');


import { app } from '../../server';
describe('Relaties', () => {
    describe('Ophalen alle relaties met: GET /api/ehrm-klantnr/relatie', () => {
        it('should get alle relaties', (done) => {

            let agent = chai.request.agent(app)
            agent
                .put('/api/ehrm-klantnr/medewerker/login')
                .send({ email: 'admin@sfgtest.com', wachtwoord: '<secret>' })
                .then(function (res) {
                    expect(res).to.have.cookie('SESSIONID');
                    // The `agent` now has the sessionid cookie saved, and will send it
                    // back to the server in the next request:
                    return agent.get('/api/ehrm-klantnr/relatie')
                        .set('meta','1')
                        .then(function (res) {
                            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                            expect(res.body.data[0].vestiging).to.equal('Slib Hoofdkantoor');
                            done();
                        });
                });
        });
    });
});
```

What does not run is this:

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import { expect } from 'chai'
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

import { app } from '../../server';
 describe('Relaties', () => {
    let agent = chai.request.agent(app);

    describe('First this one', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            console.log('outer describe - beforeEach');

            agent
                .put('/api/ehrm-klantnr/medewerker/login')
                .send({ email: 'admin@sfgtest.com', wachtwoord: '<secret>' })
                .then(function (res) {
                    expect(res).to.have.cookie('SESSIONID');
                });
        });
    });

    describe('Ophalen alle relaties met: GET /api/ehrm-klantnr/relatie', () => {
        it('should get alle relaties', (done) => {

            return agent.get('/api/ehrm-klantnr/relatie')
                .set('meta', '1')
                .then(function (res) {
                    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                    expect(res.body.data[0].vestiging).to.equal('Slib Hoofdkantoor');
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```

It is completely ignoring my before or beforeEach (both methods don't work).
Maybe chai-http does not have  before or beforeEach support ?
What am I doing wrong ?

After restructuring.

```
describe('Relaties', () => {
    const agent = chai.request.agent(app);

        beforeEach(function (done) {
            console.log('outer describe - beforeEach');

            agent
                .put('/api/ehrm-klantnr/medewerker/login')
                .send({ email: 'admin@sfgtest.com', wachtwoord: '<secret>' })
                .then(function (res) {
                    expect(res).to.have.cookie('SESSIONID');
                    done();
                });
        });


    describe('Ophalen alle relaties met: GET /api/ehrm-klantnr/relatie', () => {
        it('should get alle relaties', (done) => {

            return agent.get('/api/ehrm-klantnr/relatie')
                .set('meta', '1')
                .then(function (res) {
                    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                    expect(res).to.be.an('object');
                    expect(res.body.data).to.be.an('array');
                    expect(res.body.data[0]).to.be.an('object');
                    expect(res.body.data[0].id).to.equal(1);
                    done();
                });
        });
    });
});
```

I still get errors about the promise.

Comment: Why do you have your `beforeEach` inside a describe with no tests?  Check out this link.  It shows the right structure of tests https://mochajs.org/#hooks

Comment: I restructured the code

Comment: Thanks, See my restructuring after studying the example you send me with the asynchronous DB example.

Comment: What specific error are you seeing?  Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: SOLVED,  the problem was that I am returning the agent. So if the return in the code before the agent is removed then it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks very much Michael for your support !!!   You're examples helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is usefull for someone, this is the final solution:

```
 describe('Relaties', () => {
    const agent = chai.request.agent(app);

        beforeEach(function (done) {
            console.log('outer describe - beforeEach');

            agent
                .put('/api/ehrm-klantnr/medewerker/login')
                .send({ email: 'admin@sfgtest.com', wachtwoord: '<secret>' })
                .then(function (res) {
                    expect(res).to.have.cookie('SESSIONID');
                    done();
                });
        });


     describe('Ophalen alle relaties met: GET /api/ehrm-klantnr/relatie', () => {
        it('should get alle relaties', (done) => {

            agent.get('/api/ehrm-klantnr/relatie')
                .set('meta', '1')
                .then(function (res) {
                    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                    done();
                });
        });
    }); 
});
```